# Convert mod_rewrite rules to Zeus web server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, zeus

I need to run this Apache .htaccess file on Zeus server, but I am not sure how to make it Zeus compatible.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
#//not to effect images or style sheets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
#//not to effect directory's
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: http://support.zeus.com/zws/examples/2005/12/16/converting_apache_rules_to_zws

Comment: (This is too broad for Stack Overflow, at least these days).